# Create Multiple axis Graph on Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I want to create a multiple axis graph on Tableau. The particularity is that I want to use the same Mesures on both Y-Axis, but not the same dimension.

To make things short, i want to mix those 2 graphs:

[First Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1HiC.png)

[Second Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMSE2.png)

I apologize for the links since I'm not allowed to directly post images yet.

Comment: you want to create a graph with 3 axis?

Comment: Well, in fact i would like to display the average value for just one customer and on the same graph the average value for all the customer, to compare one customer to every other one ( if that's possible). I apologize for the late answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this [Thread](https://community.tableau.com/thread/122404) should lead to the Answer.